# How to use a Tensorflow forecasting model trained on batches for single predictions?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to train a model for univariate time series forecasting in Tensorflow. First I create a `tf.data.Dataset` from the dataframe using a window of 10 where the last value in each window is the ground truth value to be predicted. I then shuffle and split the dataset into a train/validation/test dataset using a 70%/15%/15% proportion respectively. I batch the train and validation sets with a batch size of 32.

```
df = pd.read_csv('MY.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
#extract the column we are interested in
single_col = df[['Close']]

#Convert to TFDataset
WINDOW_SIZE = 10
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((single_col_df.values))
d = dataset.window(WINDOW_SIZE, shift=1, drop_remainder=True)
d2 = d.flat_map(lambda window: window.batch(WINDOW_SIZE+1))
#create data and ground truth
d3 = d2.map(lambda window: (window[:-1], window[-1:]))

#get the total data and shuffle
len_ds = 0
for item in d2:
  len_ds +=1
d_shuffled = d3.shuffle(buffer_size=len_ds)

# split train/test
train_size = int(0.7 * len_ds)
val_size = int(0.15 * len_ds)    
test_size = int(0.15 * len_ds)
train_dataset = d_shuffled.take(train_size)
test_dataset = d_shuffled.skip(train_size)
val_dataset = test_dataset.skip(test_size)
test_dataset = test_dataset.take(test_size)
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(32).prefetch(2)
val_dataset = val_dataset.batch(32)
```

Now I define, compile and train the model. I am assuming the `input_shape` of the first GRU layer should be `[WINDOW_SIZE, 1]`, i.e., the number of past samples to be used for a new forecast and $1$ because it is a univariate model.

```
# DEFINE THE MODEL ARCHITECTURE
MODEL_ARCH = [
  tf.keras.layers.GRU(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=[WINDOW_SIZE, 1]),
  tf.keras.layers.GRU(32,),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='tanh'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh'),
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x*100)

]

# TRAIN THE MODEL
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(MODEL_ARCH)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(lr=1e-3)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer) #accuracy is a categorical metric: don't use it

history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=100, validation_data=val_dataset)
```

The problem arises when evaluating or predicting the model: I want to evaluate/predict single values instead of batches. Running `model.evaluate(test_dataset)` returns an error, I think because the training was performed on batches of 32, but `test_data` has not been batched. To do that instead I am forced to do:

```
model.evaluate(test_data.batch(1), batch_size=1)
```

But this returns a different result every time it is run. The problem I think is the fact that the after training the model with a given bath size, I then cannot use it for single prediction. I tried also to redefine the model and copy the weights as suggested by other posts, but it did not solve. The problem might involve also the input shape I set for the first layer, i.e. `[WINDOW_SIZE, 1]` since.

**OPTIONAL TIP**

Does anyone have a better way to find out the length of a `tf.data.Dataset` structure instead of looping through its elements as I did?

Comment: "Does anyone have a better way to find out the length of a tf.data.Dataset structure instead of looping through its elements as I did?" [`tf.data.Dataset.cardinality`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset?hl=en#cardinality)

Comment: `test_dataset.cardinality().numpy()`, `val_dataset.cardinality().numpy()` `train_dataset.cardinality().numpy()` are returning `-2`.

Comment: Then it returns `tf.data.experimental.UNKNOWN_CARDINALITY` meaning that tensorflow cannot infer the size of the dataset. The only solution is to loop through it.